# Shopware: Can not create variantes "(intermediate value).map is not a function"

Tags: shopware

Variant creation stucked. Console shows:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: (intermediate value).map is not a function
```

Degging deeper with the debugger `variantRestrictions` is broken in some way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the database `product.variant_restrictions` is an empty JSON array `[]`. If I change it to NULL it worked again.

You can fix it like this:

```
UPDATE product SET variant_restrictions = NULL WHERE variant_restrictions = '[]';
```

Comment: But where did that empty JSON array come from? Maybe an incomplete upgrade? Or do you have custom code which works on that column?

Comment: Was this shop migrated from Shopware 5 or something like this? Or is it a fresh installation?